# vue.js not writing out special characters correctly

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have in my vue instance a filter which is returning:

```
filters: formatPrice {
    return "€" + (2000 / 100).toFixed(2)
}
```

But when using it like this:

```
<p class="price">
  {{ product.price | formatPrice }}
</p>
```

It outputs `â‚¬20.00` instead `€20.00`

Is there something I am missing to render special characters correctly?

Comment: Is your file saved as UTF-8? Is your browser using the right encoding?

Comment: that's it, my html was missing <meta charset="UTF-8">

Comment: Glad I could serve as your debugging duck today! ;)

Comment: You should write an answer and accept it since this is resolved and could help others.

Comment: I will do, is a code sample from Vue.js in action book and it's missing the meta tag, maybe the author didnt need it in his browser

Answer (score 0):

@EmileBergeron already found a solution (missing `<meta charset="UTF-8">`), however I'd like to add that [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) method is better and more reliable way of formatting prices, because it's language sensitive:

```
(321.12).toLocaleString("pl-PL", { style: "currency", currency: "EUR" }); // => "321,12 €"

(321.12).toLocaleString("en-GB", { style: "currency", currency: "EUR" }); // => "€321.12"
```